# Leer columna de archivo .CSV

Tags: python

me gustaría poder leer la columna número 4 a partir de la fila 50, de un archivo .CSV que selecciono pero no soy capaz. El código con el que lo intento hacer es el siguiente:

```
def abrir():
archivo=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Seleccionar archivo .csv",filetypes=(("Archivos csv","*.csv"),("Todos los archivos","*.*")))
return archivo


def sacar_lineas():#me crea una lista con las lineas del texo
df=pd.read_csv(abrir())
columna=df.iloc[50:,5]
print(columna)
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

```
chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 801, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 857, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1925, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario usar pandas:

```
def extraer(nombre_archivo, indice_columna):
    numero_fila = 0
    with open(nombre_archivo, "r") as entrada:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(entrada, delimiter=',')
        for fila in csv_reader:
            yield numero_fila, fila[indice_columna]
            numero_fila += 1
```

la función extraer es un *generador* que recibe el nombre de un archivo y un indice de columna (base 0) y retorna una tupla conteniendo:

- El número de línea (base cero).
- El contenido de la columna pedida.

La gracia del generador es que al usar `yield` en lugar de `return` puede entregar un resultado y seguir ejecutando donde estaba, sin salir de la función.

Puedes usar este generador dentro de un `for` o comprensión de listas.

**Demo**

En este ejemplo extraemos la quinta columna del archivo (indice 4), a partir de la tercera línea (indice 2).

**quinta.csv**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10
1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.
11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

**código**

```
import csv

def extraer(nombre_archivo, indice_columna):
    numero_fila = 0
    with open(nombre_archivo, "r") as entrada:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(entrada, delimiter=',')
        for fila in csv_reader:
            yield numero_fila, fila[indice_columna]
            numero_fila += 1

salida = [x[1] for x in extraer("quinta.csv", 0) if x[0] >= 2]
print(salida)
```

produce:

```
['-5', '5.', '51', '5']
```